# います versus しています

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence what's the function of "して"?
私は日本語を勉強しています。
If I exclude it, does it make sense?
私は日本語を勉強います。

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching about te-form? If so, please add such attempts onto your question. Otherwise, people might vote to close your question.

Comment: I haven't. An absolute beginner here... I didn't know about te-form of verbs. I read about it after reading your comment. I'm sorry if my question has violated some rules of asking questions on this platform.

Comment: して is the te-form conjugation of する which is a verb meaning "to do". To make 'study' a verb you write 勉強する. You can't exclude して because it is part of the verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

> 私は日本語を勉強しています。

"I am studying Japanese (now)."

> 私は日本語を勉強します。

I study Japanese. or I will study Japanese.

> 私は日本語を勉強います。

This sentence just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -3):

I know I am 5 years late but for anyone else who sees this in the future, します and しています are variations of 'to do/play' and います is used in sentence structure 'to exist' for people (PLACEにPERSONはいます means 'PERSON is in PLACE')